# Is there a way to completely delete Gitlab's database?

Tags: ubuntu, gitlab

I have a peculiar use case of Gitlab for a research project, where I have to load some data to Gitlab (users, projects and merge requests) and then gather the app metrics (memory usage, latency and some others). Is there a way to completely delete the database of GitLab? I need an empty start on each run.

Through Gitlab's API I wrote a code to delete everything but sometimes seems not to be the best method. For example, after deleting everything, I get "ghost users", or can't create a user with a name that already existed on a previous run.

Also, I have to delete the metrics database from Prometheus. I'm doing:

```
sudo gitlab-ctl restart
sudo su -
cd /var/opt/gitlab/prometheus/data
rm -rf 0* wal/0* wal/checkpoint.0*
```

But sometimes it doesn't work and I have to re-install or sometimes it takes a very long time for Gitlab to restart Prometheus.

I'm using Gitlab CE 15.3.3 on an ARM64 Virtual Machine with Ubuntu 22 on it.
Any thoughts or advice?

Comment: Yes. https://about.gitlab.com/blog/2017/02/01/gitlab-dot-com-database-incident/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ideally, you would use [GitLab as a Docker image](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/install/docker.html).

That means the GitLab container would then use host mounted volumes to store persistent data.

That includes `$GITLAB_HOME/data`, where you could delete the right subfolder, and check that, upon restarting the GitLab image, you end up with a clean slate.

The [OP Francisco Zanartu](https://stackoverflow.com/users/15504210/francisco-zanartu) confirms this approach in [the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74104388/is-there-a-way-to-completely-delete-gitlabs-database/74134804#comment131008133_74134804), using "[How to access Gitlab's metrics (Prometheus and Grafana) from Docker installation?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74190119/6309)"

```
 docker run --network=host --env GITLAB_OMNIBUS_CONFIG="external_url 'http://localhost'"
```

(From "[Grafana fails GitLab OAuth when token url is not accessible](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/omnibus-gitlab/-/issues/4917#note_461092034)")

Comment: I wanted to test your solution but after installing Gitlab as a Docker image I couldn't access Prometheus on http://localhost:9090 or Grafana http://localhost/-/grafana. I'm missing something?

Comment: @FranciscoZanartu You would need to [configure Prometheus first](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/administration/monitoring/prometheus/), and [enable Grafana](https://docs.gitlab.com/omnibus/settings/grafana.html).

Comment: Found an "easier" way, which took me many hours [see here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74188436/how-to-access-gitlabs-metrics-prometheus-and-grafana-from-docker-installation/74190119#74190119), now I can test your proposal, finally!

Comment: Well, this approach works and solves my problem. Thanks

Comment: @FranciscoZanartu Great, well done! I have included your comment in the answer for more visibility. don't hesitate to edit it if I missed something.