# How to access Gitlab's metrics (Prometheus and Grafana) from Docker installation?

Tags: docker, gitlab, prometheus, grafana

I installed Gitlab using Docker image on a Ubuntu virtual machine running on a MAC M1 as follows (https://hub.docker.com/r/yrzr/gitlab-ce-arm64v8):

```
docker run \
  --detach \
  --restart always \
  --name gitlab-ce \
  --privileged \
  --memory 4096M \
  --publish 22:22 \
  --publish 80:80 \
  --publish 443:443 \
  --hostname 127.0.0.1 \
  --env GITLAB_OMNIBUS_CONFIG=" \
    nginx['redirect_http_to_https'] = true; "\
  --volume /srv/gitlab-ce/conf:/etc/gitlab:z \
  --volume /srv/gitlab-ce/logs:/var/log/gitlab:z \
  --volume /srv/gitlab-ce/data:/var/opt/gitlab:z \
  yrzr/gitlab-ce-arm64v8:latest
```

All seems to be working correctly on localhost, except that I can't access the metrics, I got unable to connect error on:

Prometheus: http://localhost:9090
Grafana: http://localhost/-/grafana

I tried enabling metrics as in the documentation, and `docker exec -it gitlab-ce gitlab-ctl reconfigure`

What I'm missing?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When Gitlab uses `localhost` this will resolve the *localhost* on the *container* and not the host (so your Mac).

There are two options to solve this:

1. Use `host.docker.internal` instead of `localhost` (this resolves to the internal IP address used by the host) - see this [doc](https://docs.docker.com/desktop/networking/#changing-internal-ip-addresses) for more info
2. Configure your container to use the host network by adding this to the docker run command: `--network=host` which will let your container and host to share the same network stack (however, this is not supported nu Docker Desktop for mac according to [this](https://docs.docker.com/network/host/))

Comment: Thanks! The second option worked for me, as I'm running Ubuntu anyway. I just had to make an extra tweak: delete ```--hostname 127.0.0.1``` add ```--env GITLAB_OMNIBUS_CONFIG="external_url 'http://localhost' ```as per [link](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/omnibus-gitlab/-/issues/4917)